# Azure Devops Notification - Subscription query

Tags: azure-devops, notifications

I am trying to create a notification to my email or teams emails but wanted to try it out with myself first on Azure.

However not sure where I am going wrong and I hope someone can point me in the correct direction.

I want to create an email notification that if any Work Item Type gets assigned to myself and the State is Changed to Ready to Test I get notified.

[image]

Any clues as to what I am clearly missing.

thanks!

Tried changing the @me to just my name and email address, have looked at the delivery settings, set it up to deliver to custom email address

Comment: I tried your subscription setting and fixed the error, i can receive the email when the work item is changed(update `assigned to` and `state` value at the same time as per your statement). Added the details below, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to create an email notification that if any Work Item Type gets assigned to myself and the State is Changed to Ready to Test I get notified.

I tried with your setting, please fix as below:

1. `Group` first two clauses `Product Backlog item` and `Bug`.
2. Use account alias not email or @me for the `assigned to` value.

[image]

Email will send to your account when you changed the `assigned to` and `state` `at the same time` for the work item.

If you still not received the email, please check on top right -> account avator -> Notification, check if the subscription is enabled on your account level.